# Homogeneous coordinates [multiple transformation]

Tags: matrix, coordinates, translation

I am actually doing some little exercices to practice about homogeneous coordinates.
Basically I have a point let's say (0,0)
And I also have a matrix :

1  0  0

0  1  0

0  0  1

And I want to compute different kind of transformations on it to come out with a final matrix that I would be able to apply to a lot of different points for example :
A translation with x = -4 and y = -3
A Homothecy with x = 2 and y = 1

I come out with this final matrix :

2  0  -4

0  1  -3

0  0  1

I kinda start to understand how things work with homogeneous coordinates but I am not really confident about it. All the examples I found on Internet are about generalizing matrix and all, I would love some more concrete explanations that I could simply understand to be able to continue on my way. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply transformations using matrices you multiple the transformation matrix by the transpose of the vector of coordinates (the transpose is just converting the 'horizontal' matrix to be 'vertical', explained below).

There is a simple rule for what is a valid matrix multiplication:

To multiply an NxM matrix with an OxP matrix, M and O must be the same. The result will be an NxP matrix.

You will not be able to multiply your 3x3 matrix on 2D vectors, but you can with 3D vectors.

Rotation is a typical example, I will try to explain it in 2 dimensions.

A 2D rotation matrix can be constructed as so:

```
R = |cos(theta), -sin(theta)|
    |sin(theta), cos(theta) |
```

To perform rotation on a 2D vector V (which is a 1x2 matrix) using this matrix you would perform:

```
R x V(transpose)
```

where V(transpose) simple flips V so that it is 2x1 matrix instead of 1x2 and therefore can be multiplied on the right side of R.

Translations are simpler, to translate say [1,2] by x=-1 and y=2 you would simply add the 2 vectors [1,2] and [-1,2] together, giving [0, 4].

Also I found [this](https://www.coursera.org/course/matrix) course about matrices on Coursera to be very good.

Comment: I knew about the rule of matrix multiplication but you pointed a lot of thing I was ignoring with the transpose part. I figured out what I was doing wrong ( V(transpose) * R instead of R * V(transpose) )